# DC to AC Inverter for WPT

Tags: wireless, inverter, dc-ac

I'm working on a batteryless mouse, and it will be wirelessly powered by the USB (5V 0.5A), however, I already  stepped up the voltage to 12VDC. From what I understand, I will need a DC to AC inverter circuit to convert the 12VDC to AC for Wireless Power Transfer (WPT). Correct me if I'm wrong, the signal has to be in high frequency (100KHz to 500KHz) to transfer the power efficiently. Can anyone please suggest me a proper inverter circuit for that application? FYI, I'm a mechanical eng. student, if you have better idea for my project, let me know!

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at [TI's](http://www.ti.com/lsds/ti/power-management/wireless-power-receiver-solutions-overview.page) and [Linear's](http://www.linear.com/parametric/Wireless_Power_Transfer) options for wireless power transfer. Keep in mind that designing such a system will require a reasonable sound knowledge of electromagnetics and electronics design.

Comment: @uint128_t noted. but still got no clue after visiting the sites. Can you give me some more details?

Comment: What sort of range are you looking at? A pad for the mouse to sit on just for recharging or a constant source of power while it's being used?

Comment: @Finbarr yes, it is a mouse pad connected to the USB, that constantly transferring power to the mouse.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's correct - due to air core "transformer" there is need high frequency to transmit power with good efficiency.
Check currently applicable standards: Qi and A4WP. 
Note that you need not only inverter - rectifier receiver too. As it was said the best option it's to use dedicated drivers. But educationally you can build your own driver too (it won't be easy).
Here examples of schematic from EPC9113 eval board:
[image: Transmitter]

[image: Receiver]